# Looking for a way to automate/script reading WSDL/XSD Files for data constraints

Tags: xml, soap, groovy, xsd, wsdl

I've been in my current position for over a year and I'm always looking for ways to improve efficiency or to automate as much of the Software Testing process as I can. The issue at hand is that what I call the analysis phase takes forever and I have to think there's a way out there to do this better or even automated.

Here's what I have: We receive WSDL/Schema files that we develop to. These are typically split between a Write-based service and a Read-based service. Analysis is basically building our initial SoapUI NG Pro test project, and verifying there are no schema defects between the Write XML element definitions and what the Read defines these same elements as.

For example, one thing that I run in to is a Write-based element may have to conform to being a string that matches the regex "[A-Z0-9]{1,32}" but the Read service might define this element as having a regex of "[A-Z0-9]{2,10}". This is what I refer to as a schema defect, due to the inconsistency between what can be used in the Create service and what can be returned by the Read service.

Typically we go through the "Create" request one line at a time and notate every element and its constraints. We keep a list, then build a groovy script to generate sample/test data to use. We work with Virts in SoapUI to check the constraints and make sure everything matches.

So far, this method has been great. The problem is when we have a Create request that is 30,000 lines long. Doing analysis on this in our traditional manner is astronomical in how long that would take.

What I am looking for help with is a way to write a script and/or app to parse through the XML request for the Create method, and to output a list of every element and its constraints. I've looked high and low on here, and with my google-fu, but have yet to find anything that suits my needs.

Does anyone have any ideas?

To explain a little more, let's say I have a WSDL/XSD set for a Write service, where I have an add request. Every element\child element\etc in the request is going to have certain definitions of what its constraints are. There's inherently no easy way for a list of what all of the elements in a request are from the XSD. I am looking for steps/guidance on potential ways of automating that.

---

MORE INFORMATION:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <writeID>
      <key>00000000000000000000000000000000</key>
      <date>20160101T00:00:00Z</date>
      <firstName>TEST</firstName>
      <qty>10</qty>
      <enabled>true</enabled>
      <status>PENDING</status>
    </writeID>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

There's a sample Write Soap request that writes the provided data to a database, using KEY as the identifier. Every element is going to have certain constraints on what the data has to match. String with a regex, a dateTime, an enumerated list, etc.

The Read version will query based off of different elements, but may provide different constraints for some of the fields. A common schema defect I see is the write service may define firstName as a string that has to match this regex "[A-Z0-9]{1, 10}" but the read service may require that in its response that firstName must be "[A-Z0-9]{2,10}" and that would introduce schema invalid data. What can be written (a firstName element of one character is perfectly acceptable) would fail schema compliance if that data was returned, since the minimum length is 2.

So part and parcel of what I do is I go through the Write request line by line and figure out data constraints. I write a groovy script to generate this data. For a small request like this, you're talking minutes to do. Not bad. Some of my services are 30,000 elements. That gets cumbersome quickly.

I am looking for something to parse a method definition quickly to output something like:
     Key: String, [A-Z0-9]{1,32}
     date: dateTime
     firstName: String, [A-Z0-9]{1,10}
     qty: Integer, min value 1, max value 999
     enabled: boolean
     Status: String, enumerated list ["PENDING", "NEW", "DISABLED"]

Where each of those are how the element is defined/constrained in the XSD file.

Comment: Can you give a simple example of what you're trying to achieve? As it stands, I don't think this question is answerable, and is likely to be closed as too broad

Comment: The best example I can give is I have two sets of WSDL/XSD Files. One set is for a Write service. The other is for a Read service pull back data inserted by the Write.

Ultimately, my first phase of testing is verifying these schemas are defect free and are consistent. The only way I have of doing this currently is to parse through the Write service's ADD request manually, notating what every element is and what all of the constraints of said elements are.

I want to find a way to automate parsing a Soap request and giving me all elements and what their XML definitions/constraints are.

Comment: That's what your question already says, and is not a simple example of the inputs you have and the desired output

Comment: I cannot give you a detailed example, as I cannot go posting my actual requests on here. I'll try to mock something up.

Comment: Cool, I'm not after a detailed example, just a simple one that demonstrates the problem and can be worked against

Comment: I am attaching a more detailed description in the original problem. :)